# Why does the function take an int, but does nothing when a variable is passed through?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
  $array = $product->get_trims2($year);
  for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); ++$i) {
    var_dump((int)$array[$i]["car_trim"]);
    $item = $product->get_trim_by_id((int)$array[$i]["car_trim"]); //line of code in question
    var_dump($item);
  }
```

will output:

`int(29)
array(0) {
}`

```
  $array = $product->get_trims2($year);
  for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); ++$i) {
    var_dump((int)$array[$i]["car_trim"]);
    $item = $product->get_trim_by_id(29); //line of code in question
    var_dump($item);
  }
```

Will output:

`int(29)
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(10) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "29"
    [0]=>
    string(2) "29"
    ["year"]=>
    string(4) "2016"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "2016"
    ["make"]=>
    string(3) "bmw"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "bmw"
    ["model"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["trim"]=>
    string(22) "With OEM HID Headlamps"
    [4]=>
    string(22) "With OEM HID Headlamps"
  }
}`

used function:

```
public function get_trim_by_id($id)
{
    $query = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `custom_trims` WHERE `id` = ?");
    $query->bindValue(1, $id);
    $query->execute();
    return $query->fetchAll();
}
```

Comment: This is not intended to solve your problem but [as per the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) you can specify what kind of variable bindValue will bind by supplying a 3rd argument. might help.

Comment: `var_dump($id)` inside a function

Comment: @u_mulder, that's just for testing purposes, but when I hard code an int in the function, it works. Otherwise, variables that contain int will not work.

Comment: Please, `var_dump` inside a function. It is simple, isn't it?

Comment: I think you could use `intval($array[$i]["car_trim"])` instead since it is a function.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `bindValue(1, $id)` use `bindParam(1, $id)` to pass a variable value. It looks like a matter of execution time and the value assigned by bind value.

You could read more here:

http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

Comment: It still doesn't work. It's notable that the mysql query's `execute` returns true, while the `fetchAll` returns  an empty array and `fetch` returns false.

Comment: Because bindValue uses a value and mantain it, while bindParam is prepared for using variables where value can change. So I thougth that could be the solution in this case. The execution it's going to return true because that doesn't avoid execution, but could pass a invalid value, so the array could be return empty.